# BreezeJS and executing Entity Framework Stored Procedures

Tags: breeze

I have a SQL Stored Procedure that just returns a Boolean that I need to call from Breeze.  How can I go about doing this?  All I have seen is an example of calling a stored proc that returns an entity.  I have also read somewhere that Breeze needs stored procedures to return an entity that Breeze has the Metadata for.  Is this true, or can you call stored procs that just return a boolean value?

Thank you,

RG

Comment: Since there were no replies I ended up using a Web API call via AJAX.  Really wish I could have made this work using Breeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used ASP.NET Web API call to the stored procedure, and used AJAX to do the Web API call from the app.